# React Testing Library - how to set initial value of state variable

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

i have the following react counter application

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Counter = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter((value) => value + 1 );
        }}
        type='button'
        value={`${counter}`}
      >
       {counter}
      </button>
      <button
        disabled={counter > 2 ? false : true}
        type='button'
        value={`${counter}`}
        data-testid='counterBtn'
      >
        Exit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

now i want to test the application by setting the initial value of the counter greater than 2 in my test case and check if the button is enabled. How can i set the initial value of the counter for the below test case?

```
  it('Enable button if counter is greater than 2'), () => {
      const { getByTestId } = CounterRender();
      const btn = getByTestId('counterBtn');
      expect(getByTestId('counterBtn')).toBeEnabled();
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The main principle of react-testing-library is to test the how your web pages are interacted by the users and **not** the implementation details.

So, you can write a test to simulate a click on your button, making the state to increment to 2. And then assert if the button is disabled. *(since this is the way user will interact with your component)*

You can use `fireEvent` or `userEvent (recommended)` for simulating the clicks.

```js
    const { getByTestId } = CounterRender();
    const btn = getByTestId('counterBtn');
    
    // simulate click with userEvent
    userEvent.click(btn); // counter will be 1 after this
    userEvent.click(btn); // counter will be 2 after this

    // your assertion here
    expect(getByTestId('counterBtn')).toBeEnabled();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set your **useState** counter to 2.

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(2);
```

Comment: for this example yes. but on a real time application i would want to enable the button when the user input length is greater than 10. how can i write a test case without disturbing the logic in my code?